# 'wix execute batch before uninstall with administrator

Tags: wix, uninstallation, custom-action, servicecontroller

My WiX XML file installs app that contains windows-service named OLOLO_SERVICE (for example). I want to stop this service when installing/reinstalling my app.

I use CustomAction with ExeCommand='sc stop OLOLO_SERVICE'.

```
<CustomAction Id='EnsureThatServiceIsStopped' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION' 
Impersonate="no" Execute="immediate" ExeCommand="sc 
stop OLOLO_SERVICE" Return="ignore" />
```

Inside <InstallExecuteSequence> tag is action

```
<Custom Action='EnsureThatServiceIsStopped' Before='InstallValidate' />
```

But this doesn't works, uninstaller shows this window "For uninstallation continue you should stop following executables" (maybe not 100% correct, because in my russian Windows 7 it is written in russian).

I think that possible reasons for this are

- script runs before admin rights taken (and stopping service fails because it needs admin privilegies)
- script runs after validation (and validation fails when checking installed executables)

Plesae help me, I want to stop service using batch 'sc stop OLOLO_SERVICE'

PS. I decided to simplify a question: I want my WiX to execute 'sc stop OLOLO_SERVICE' with administrator privilegies and before checking for running applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do this in a batch file, you can use the [ServiceControl](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_servicecontrol.htm) element:

```
<ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl_OloService" 
                Name="OLOLO_SERVICE"
                Stop="both"
                Remove="uninstall"
                Wait="yes" />
```